# I have written the following code in html and have included the php file in the same directory then why is it that i am not getting any output

Tags: php, html, forms

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
NAME:<input type="text" name="name"></input><br>
EMAIL:<input type="text" name="email"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

the php code is

```
    <html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST["name"];
echo "echo inside php";
?>
<?php

echo $_POST["email"];
?>

This is some dummy text
</body>

</html>
```

I am using the wamp server but the output does not show nothing from the php code why is that?
the echo statement in the php file is also not executed.
Is this some programming error or some other type of problem.

Comment: What *specifically* is returned from the server?  Is there anything in the PHP error logs?  Have you enabled error reporting in PHP?

Comment: How to do that?Can you please tell me I am fairly new at this.

Comment: You have not posted or submitted anything to the script with the PHP in it. Please take some time to go through some PHP tutorials and you will see how this works.

Comment: @KaranSharma: For the first suggestion, just *look at* what's coming back from the server.  (The network tab in your browser's debugging tools will be helpful too.)  For the second one, Google "PHP error logs".  For the third one, Google "PHP error reporting".

Comment: Are you accessing the html file directly or through localhost.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you press submit on your form, you do see "This is some dummy text"?

Comment: @PhilS Yes I do see "This is some dummy text" when submit is pressed

Comment: If you change that to `This is some <?php echo "dummy"; ?> text` 
Do you see "This is some dummy text" or "This is some  text"?

Comment: I see "This is some text". The dummy is not printing.

Comment: What is the URL you are using to view your form? Is it something like `http://localhost/index.html` like prabhjot mentioned?

Answer (score -3):

I used XAMPP and it seems to be working fine. If you have started your server, type "http://localhost/index.html" into your URL bar and submit the form. This should echo the output to the browser.